# SQL Insert Into two Tables Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, insert

I am using a stored procedure to insert data into a database, when it is inserted it is automatically given a ID that is an identity, it also the Primary Key of the table. I also need to insert data into a second table of which that ID is one of the columns that needs to be inserted. But it the ID hasnt been created yet, so I was wondering how would you guys go about solving this problem. I need it so when they submit my form that it inserts the user, and then I need to add it to a table that basically will document that user being created. Is this possible.? I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (SomeColumn) Values ('SomeValue')

DECLARE @NewIdent int
SELECT @NewIdent = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Table2 (SomeColumn, T1ID) VALUES ('SomeValue',@NewIDent)
```

You can look at what @@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), and IDENT_CURRENT to see which one will fit your needs best.  I suspect SCOPE_IDENTITY will do the job.

[Here is a good article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) on what they all do.

Answer (score 2):

Use the output clause to get the id from the first insert and use that value inthe second insert.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the result of the scope_identity() system function after the first insert; it will contain the ID of the previously-inserted record (assuming the ID is auto-generated using an identity column). As stated in the comments, it is better than using @@identity because @@identity can be inaccurate or cause problems when triggers are present in the database or in high-traffic situations where queries can be pre-empted.

Comment: @@identity has serious issues when triggers are present, and possibly in high usage systems where queries are prone to interrupting each other.

Comment: I give; answer edited. Personally I avoid triggers, as they contain business logic that is much easier to develop, test and maintain up in the application layer. But, they are still useful, and in such a case you guys are right.

Answer (score 0):

U can get new identity inserted using SCOPE_IDENTITY()